# Install Ubuntu on Yosemite - no detected operating system

Tags: unix

I have a 2012 MBP running Yosemite and a Live CD of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It runs fine, but when I get to the install part it only gives me options to delete the hard disk (no operating system detected) or something else (which im not comfortable with).

I've googled for hours and still am no where. Has anyone had this issue/know how to get around it?

Comment: Suggest that you look at this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/462360/macbook-air-how-to-install-a-dual-bootable-ubuntu-14-04-lts -  on askubuntu.com. Though this covers 14.04, the procedure is the same for 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a hard drive partition that is formatted in the way Ubuntu uses. You can't do that using Yosemite so you will have to do it via the live cd using the disk utility. A nice guide can be found here -> http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/ubuntu-1204-lts/hard-disk-partition/